Css problem with area for the effect :hover


.navbar
{
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding: 5px;
}
.navbar li
{
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 200px;
  top: -5px;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.navbar li:nth-child(2) a:hover + .connection-navbar li:first-child
{
  display: block;
  left: 214px;

}
.navbar li:nth-child(2) :hover + .connection-navbar li:nth-child(2)
{
  display: block;
  left: 214px;
}

.connection-navbar
{
  list-style-type: none;
  
}
.connection-navbar li
{
  position: relative;
  line-height: 4em;
  display: none;
  

}
<ul class="navbar">
        <li>
            <a href="">Accueil</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="">Se connecter</a>
        
        <ul class="connection-navbar">
            <li>
                <a href="">Se connecter via e-mail</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Se connecter via nom d'utilisateur</a>
            </li>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>



I'd like to define a box in which my :hover effect can remain active, because my problem is as follows: when I hover over my “log in” field I can actually see my other two elements displayed unfortunately I don't know how to keep it active as long as the user is in a certain predefined area, I started css very recently and it's for a python project (I work with the flask framework) I tried putting a margin to my “log in” field unfortunately the links shook and were displayed then removed, if anyone has an idea it would help me a lot.
I tried with a margin on my “connect” field, thinking it would make the “box” that would keep the effect active. Unfortunately, the margin collided with my other two fields.

Please post an [mre]. It might also be a good idea to describe the broader problem you’re trying to solve (what is the purpose of the other two elements?), because there may be a more suitable broader solution.

I want to have 2 fields one named " se connecter via email " and another one named " se connecter via nom d'utilisateur " which means that I want a navigation bar for all my pages and when an user put his mouse on the field " se connecter " you can see the two other fields appear, the problem is I can't figure out how to make the effect :hover still work in a predefined zone

The problem is because the connection-navbar isn't remain over li parent, so you can do this.
First your HTML is wrong, you close the ul after the li.
Second in css try this below.


.navbar
{
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding: 5px;
}
.navbar > li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.navbar li:hover {
  border: solid 1px #00f;
}

.navbar .connection-navbar {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 25px;
  
  width: 250px;
  
  list-style-type: none;
  border: solid 1px #f00;  
}

.navbar .connection-navbar li {
  line-height: 4em;
}

.navbar li:hover .connection-navbar {
  display: block;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Accueil</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\static\css\styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li>
                <a href="{{ url_for('index')}}">Accueil</a>
            </li>

            <li>
               <a href="">Se connecter</a>
               <ul class="connection-navbar">
                  <li>
                      <a href="{{ url_for('loginByEmail')}}">Se connecter via e-mail</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="{{ url_for('loginByUsername')}}">Se connecter via nom d'utilisateur</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>



I added position: absolute; on connection-navbar and I added too position: relative; on li parent.
With this the connection-navbar will remain over li hovered and won't close when you hover on it.
LI in blue and the connection-navbar in red

I'm too tired to try and understand the changes, I've been working on the same problem for 2 days now and I've been struggling day and night, even though for some it may be simple, in any case it works I've just tried it I'm going to look at your changes tomorrow and understand my error(s), thank you so much for the helping hand you've saved me precious time!

I didn't change a lot of, I only remove:
.navbar li:nth-child(2) a:hover + .connection-navbar li:first-child
{
display: block;
left: 214px;
}
.navbar li:nth-child(2) :hover + .connection-navbar li:nth-child(2)
{
display: block;
left: 214px;
}
'cause you can do this effect adding in only one element. In navbar > li I added position: absolute, and in connection-navbar I added this:
position: absolute; - remain over LI parent
display: none; - will only be displayed only if the parent is hovering
left: 0; - stay in left side
top: 25px; - stay 25px below the parent

But try relax, cold your mind and tomorrow your code will be work

Thanks man, I really appreciate it, it still working I just don't understand everything I'm lacking with css boxs, margin, padding, inheritance, I'm gonna focus on the back end app I was too much on the front end side this last 2 days, but your modifications really help me a lot, I hope I can help you too one day ! :)
